# Rsync from Cpanel to Synology

Tags: server, cpanel, configuration, backups, whm

I'm trying to add a Rsync destination for backup in whm, but I keep getting this error when validating

> Error:Validation for transport “NAS2” failed: Can't ssh to
>   [the Ip Address]: unable to establish master SSH connection: bad password or master process exited unexpectedly at
>   /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Transport/Files/Rsync.pm line 260.

[image]

The password is correct, the user has the rsync permissions, the ssh is enabled. 
Any idea please?